# VBA function over visible range only

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run the PercentRank function over an autofiltered spreadsheet such that it only runs over visible cells. I tried defining a range object ie:

```
Dim x As Range
x = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K6027").Rows.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeVisible)
```

And then tried using that range the function ie:

```
PercentRank = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(Range(x, *value to be ranked*) )
```

But that code returns a "compile error : argument not optional" message. I'm assuming it's due to the syntax of the percentrank function requiring two arguments to set yhe range of values it runs over, but I'm just not clear conceptually then on how to translate that into code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. you are getting that error because you are including the second criterion in the range, the `)` is in the wrong space. 2. `x` is already a range object so you do not need the Range(): `WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(x, *value to be ranked* )` 3. I do not think Percent Rank will work with a disjointed range.  So you may need to write out the code to do the work long hand in the vba, You may need to loop through the range.

Comment: An alternate to having vba to do the work long hand (if needed) is to copy the disjointed range to a random column in the worksheet to make it contiguous and then call the `PercentRank` against that. Still a work around, but probably cleaner and less code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I don't know, it is a simple loop to count the number below the second criterion and divided it by the count of cells in the range.  Or, as I think of it, Loop trough the groups and use countif() to get the count and divide by the total number of cells.  Either method will be pretty quick.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I was thinking more in terms of lines of code. But it's probably 6 one way and 1/2 dozen the other :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman or if the criteria for the filter is simple, a COUNTIFS() divided by a COUNTIF() will do it also.

Comment: and there is a typo in `x1CellTypeVisible` which should be `xlCellTypeVisible`. Means second character should be a lower case `L` not a one.

Comment: @Scott Craner I should note that while the worksheet is filtered, the criterion by which it is filtered is already sorted such that each filtered result is a continuous range of rows. So for example the first autofilter result returns rows 1-40, the second autofilter returns rows 41-100, etc. Do you think that would still pose an issue for PercentRank?

Comment: @ChipsAhoy nope, I was in error on the disjointed range, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `Set` x and use that. Also, your brackets need shifting around:

```
Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K6027").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
MyPercentRank  = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(x, *value to be ranked*)
```

Comment: I do not believe that the PercentRank will work with a disjointed range.

Comment: @ScottCraner It does.

Comment: @peh so it does.

Comment: @CLR thank you I tried this and it fixed the syntax issue, but I'm now getting a run time error 1004 "Unable to get the SpecialCells property of the Range class". Any insight as to that issue?

Comment: @ChipsAhoy did you replace your line with his, you had a typo in the `xlCellTypeVisible`  See Peh's comment above.

Comment: @ChipsAhoy This error occurs when the `*value to be ranked*` is not found within the `Range("K1:K6027")`.

Comment: @Peh, I've just tried this myself (was building a UDF to fill out my answer) and I'm hitting a problem where `x.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` doesn't give me a different range to `x` - I've tried manually hiding and using a filter.. Any clues?

Comment: @Peh It works! Using the code CLR posted and correcting the typo in xlCellTypeVisible fixed the issue. Thank you all so much! You are geniuses

Comment: @CLR not clear about how to understand your question but if you `Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K6027").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and `Debug.Print x.Address` gives you `$K$1:$K$6027`. If I use the group data (don't know the correct term in english, sorry) and hide row 6+7  I get `$K$1:$K$5,$K$8:$K$6027`.

Comment: That's most odd @Peh - as when I try that I get `$K$1:$K$6027` for both, despite some rows being hidden by a filter.

Comment: Did you clear out the typo in `xlCellTypeVisible` I mentioned in the comments of the question (I edited that in your answer already)? Therefore I always use `Option Explicit` to prevent typos like that.

Comment: I did, and thank-you for spotting that. I might post my UDF in a new question for all to look at.