# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) not working in UDF

Tags: vba, excel

Based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232697) posed by @Chips Ahoy, I decided to create a UDF to find the PercentRank of visible cells in a range.

While @Chips seems happy with my syntax correction, I am actually unable to get my UDF to work correctly.

When I run the below, the two addresses output read identical. In my example using a formula of `=VisiblePercentRank($A$2:$A$41,0.5)` , both addresses output to the immediate window read `$A$2:$A$41`, despite rows 3 to 11 being hidden by an autofilter.

**Code:**

```
Function VisiblePercentRank(x As Range, RankVal As Double)
    Debug.Print x.Address, x.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
    VisiblePercentRank = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(x.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), RankVal)
End Function
```

**Also** tried removing `.Rows`:

```
Function VisiblePercentRank(x As Range, RankVal As Double)
    Debug.Print x.Address, x.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
    VisiblePercentRank = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(x.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), RankVal)
End Function
```

Should the second output not read `$A$2,$A$12:$A$41` or have I missed something?

Using Excel/Office 2013, 64bit on Win7, 64bit.

**BRAIN FRYING UPDATE**

I have found that my UDF works if I run it from the immediate window:

```
?VisiblePercentRank(range("A2:A41"),0.5)
$A$2:$A$41    $A$2:$A$11,$A$39:$A$41
 0.207
```

But if run from an in-cell formula of `=VisiblePercentRank(A2:A41,0.5)`:

```
$A$2:$A$41    $A$2:$A$41
```

Comment: Remove the `Rows.` : `x.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address`

Comment: Tried that @ScottCraner, no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that `SpecialCells` is known to fail in UDFs. *A few sources: [1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/udf-not-working-properly-count-comments/d586fa6b-5d44-405b-9471-946ddd2250e6), [2](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/863981-vba-range-specialcells-xlcelltypevisible-not-working-as-a-udf-print.html), [3](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671676-specialcells-xlcelltypevisible-not-working-function.html)*

You'd have to create your own function. Perhaps something like this:

```
Function VisiblePercentRank(x As Range, RankVal As Double)
    Debug.Print x.Address, VisibleCells(x).Address
    VisiblePercentRank = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(VisibleCells(x), RankVal)
End Function

Private Function VisibleCells(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If VisibleCells Is Nothing Then
                Set VisibleCells = r
            Else
                Set VisibleCells = Union(VisibleCells, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @CallumDA, that's perfect. Looks like Microsoft have a bug to fix and no appetite to do it.