# How to get filtered data as rowsource of multicolumn listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in `Sheet2` as like below.
***Actual Data***
[image: Actual Data]

Then I manually apply filer to those data which looks like...
***Filtered Data***
[image]

I have a user form (UserForm1) and a list box (`ListBox1`) in the form. Also have a command button `cmdFilteredData`. So, I want to fill the listbox with filtered data only. I make below codes but it gives `Type mismatch` error.

```
Private Sub cmdFilteredData_Click()
Dim FilteredRange As Range
    Set FilteredRange = Sheet2.Range("A1:C5").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With Me.ListBox1

        .ColumnCount = 3
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
        .RowSource = FilteredRange
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help is hearty appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to populate the `ListBox1` with values from filtered range, you have blank rows in the middle, this "messes" up the `ListBox`.

Instead, you can copy>>Paste the value to columns on the right (or another worksheet), use an array to populate these values, and then populate the `ListBox1` with the array.

**Code**

```
Private Sub cmdFilteredData_Click()

Dim FilteredRange As Range
Dim myArr As Variant

Set FilteredRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A1:C5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' copy filtered range to the columns on the right (if you want, you can add a "Dummy" sheet), to have the range continous
FilteredRange.Copy Range("Z1")

' populae the array with new range values (without blank rows in the middle)
myArr = Range("Z1").CurrentRegion

With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
    .List = (myArr)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I accept your answer as your codes server my purpose. I can also achieve it by advance filter `Copy To` feather using vba code. Whatever thanks for your effort.

Comment: `SpecialCells` seem to be known as unreliable (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234354/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-not-working-in-udf), even within this small example range. Suggest also to clear the target row via `Range("Z1").Offset(0, 25).Value = ""`

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Function to - unreliable - SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)**

This answer intends to *complete* Shai Rado's appreciated solution, not to correct it.

Testing the above solution, however showed that using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and/or reference to `CurrentRegion` might result in problems (even within OP's small range).
A possible work around function (esp. for udfs) is presented at [SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) not working in UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234354/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-not-working-in-udf).

```
Private Function VisibleCells(rng As Range) As Range
' Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234354/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-not-working-in-udf
' Note: as proposed by CalumDA
Dim r As Range
For Each r In rng
    If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If VisibleCells Is Nothing Then
            Set VisibleCells = r
        Else
            Set VisibleCells = Union(VisibleCells, r)
        End If
    End If
Next r
End Function
```

**Shai Rado's solution slightly modified (cf. above notes)**

In any case the target range has to be *cleared* before copying and then better referenced *without* `CurrentRegion`, so that you get the wanted items only. These changes worked for me.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdFilteredData_Click()

Dim ws            As Worksheet
Dim sRng          As String
Dim FilteredRange As Range
Dim myArr         As Variant
Dim n             As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filtered")
n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row
sRng = "A1:C" & n

' Set FilteredRange = ws.Range(sRng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)    ' << not reliable
  Set FilteredRange = VisibleCells(ws.Range(sRng))       ' <<<< possible ALTERNATIVE 

' clear target range in order to allow correct array fillings later !
  ws.Range("Z:AAB").Value = ""
' copy filtered range to the columns on the right
  FilteredRange.Copy ws.Range("Z1")

' populate the array with new range values (without blank rows in the middle)
' myArr = ws.Range("Z1").CurrentRegion         ' sometimes unreliable, too
  myArr = ws.Range("Z1:AAB" & ws.Range("Z" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) ' <<< better than CurrentRegion
With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
    .List = (myArr)
End With

End Sub
```

**Links mentioned in cited post:**

[Microsoft - udf not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/udf-not-working-properly-count-comments/d586fa6b-5d44-405b-9471-946ddd2250e6)

[ExcelForum - xlCelltypeVisible not working](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/863981-vba-range-specialcells-xlcelltypevisible-not-working-as-a-udf-print.html)

[MrExcel - SpecialCells not working](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671676-specialcells--not-working-function.html)

Comment: I up vote your answer as it also works but this method works slowly. @T.M

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look on a fast approach how to show results filtered immediately only by changing a given search condition via textbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel/47003993#47003993 - sure you could adapt this for your demands. @harun224h -

Comment: I had a look to your provided link. It is faster approach to add data to `Listbox` but the codes you provided by answer slower to extract visible data (Filtered data). My actual purpose is solved by both of your provided codes.

Comment: Glad you could meet both ends to a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching a lot for that but I couldn't fine any elegant solution for doing it without pasting data in the sheet. So I create my own function to convert visible cells of range into an array.

Maybe it's not the smartest way, but works just fine an quite fast.

```
Function createArrFromRng(rng As Range)
Dim sCellValues() As Variant
Dim col, row, colCount, RowCount As Integer

col = 0
row = 0
colCount = 0
RowCount = 0

On Error GoTo theEnd
Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'get the columns and rows size
For Each cell In rng

    If col < cell.Column Then
        colCount = colCount + 1
    Else
        colCount = 1
    End If
    col = cell.Column
    
    If row < cell.row Then
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    End If
    row = cell.row

Next cell

'set the array size
ReDim Preserve sCellValues(RowCount - 1, colCount - 1)
col = 0
row = 0
colCount = 0
RowCount = 0

'get the values and add to the array
For Each cell In rng

    If col < cell.Column Then
        colCount = colCount + 1
    Else
        colCount = 1
    End If
    col = cell.Column
    'Debug.Print colCount
    
    If row < cell.row Then
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
    End If
    row = cell.row

    sCellValues(RowCount - 1, colCount - 1) = cell.value

Next cell

theEnd:
createArrFromRng = sCellValues

End Function
```

Comment: So, did the question and answer helped you?

Comment: Not much, I had to build a new function for what I needed, so now I just wanted to share another solution. =)

Comment: This seems like the best solution, if it works. doesn't require copying data to a different range.