# How to search specified column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search data on the basis of column number "C".

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Me.TextBox1 = Format(StrConv(Me.TextBox1, vbUpperCase))

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim p As Long

Me.ListBox1.Clear

'Display Header

Me.ListBox1.AddItem "Product Name"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = "HSN Code"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Quantity"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Rate"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = "GST"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = "Total"

Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

For i = 2 To sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 2))
p = Me.TextBox1.TextLength

If UCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 2), x, p)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then

With ListBox1

.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 2)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 3)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 4)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 5)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 6)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 7)
End With

End If
Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

On basis of First Column "B" The result are displayed.

I want to search on the basis of Column "C".

Excel sheet2 Data:

[image]

When I enter in text Box HSN1 the Data should be displayed in Listbox and Not on basis of AB.

My output: When I enter HSN2 in Textbox

Output:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show your expected output (listbox scenario)?

Comment: [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246393/how-to-get-filtered-data-as-rowsource-of-multicolumn-listbox).

Comment: @Harun24HR look at the Output i have updated the question with expected output ... i have highlighted it with yellow for your reference ... as i enter HSN2 the record should be displayed in ListBox ... entire code is working perfect when i enter AB1 ... or AB2... but i want to search and display on basis of Column "C"  which is HSN Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(sh.Cells(i, 2)` is looking at the values of column "B".

Try using `sh.Range("C" & i).Value` instead.

See section of modified code below:

```
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear

    'Display Header
    .AddItem "Product Name"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "HSN Code"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Quantity"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Rate"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = "GST"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = "Total"

    .Selected(0) = True
End With

For i = 2 To sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 1 To Len(sh.Range("C" & i).Value)
        p = Me.TextBox1.TextLength

        If UCase(Mid(sh.Range("C" & i).Value, x, p)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then
            With ListBox1
                .AddItem sh.Range("B" & i).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Range("F" & i).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Range("G" & i).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

Screen-shot of the result :
[image]