# From sub to Function

Tags: excel, vba

The objective is to count the number of comments in a range with a Function (not a sub).

I am trying to convert a Sub into a Function as I would like the range to vary and the user to enter as a formula

I have already searched the internet and got the right function. However for the sake of learning need to know why my Sub works and the Function does not

```
Function CommentsCounter(myRange3 As Range) As Long

'This one is mine - not working

CommentsCounter = myRange3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).Count

End Function

Sub working_just_fine()

'This one is working

Dim myRange4 As Range

Set myRange4 = Range("CO1:CO497")

Range("CO505").Value = myRange4.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).Count

End Sub
```

Its giving the total number of cells and not the number of comments in the range

Comment: Are you passing the correct argument to `myRange3`? Would look something like `MsgBox CommentsCounter(Range("CO1:CO497"))` And on a side note, I would recommend that you always qualify your range objects with at the very least your worksheet, but workbook is strongly preferred as well.

Comment: SpecialCells doesn't work in a user-defined function when called from a worksheet.  See for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234354/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-not-working-in-udf

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I tried some wonky stuff like declaring a public variable, then calling a `Sub` from the `Function` and putting the result of `SpecialCells.Count` into the public variable and accessing that from the `Function`. Surprisingly, calling the `Sub` from the `Function` led to a different result than calling the `Sub` separately. As a solution, this `Function` should do what you're trying to achieve, although it may be a bit slow on very large ranges, since it goes through every single cell in the range (I haven't done extensive testing on it yet):

```
Function CommentsCounter(myRange3 As Range) As Long

CommentsCounter = 0
For Each rngCell In myRange3
    If Not rngCell.Comment Is Nothing Then CommentsCounter = CommentsCounter + 1
Next

End Function
```